# Bash: Is memory leak applicable for a bash script in UNIX?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, memory-leaks, scripting

I want to know if there are memory leak issues possible with bash scripts ?

Do the system will automatically take care of freeing the memory after the execution or Is there any explicit commands that we have to use in shell scripts (like free command in C++) ? If yes, what kind of commands will cause a memory leak problem .

How to check the memory usage of the shell script (like stack space,heap space, text space ) ?

Any info is appreciated as I am not much aware about the memory management in a bash script .

Comment: The bash which you get with your distribution should a stable bug-free version.Why not get the bash source [\[ code \]](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash) and compile a debug version if you suspect leaks.

Comment: Also check [\[ debugging \]](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html) bash scripts.

Comment: Thanks for the link @sjsam . But I was specifically looking for the memory management perspectives for a bash script .

Comment: In my experience. Yes! If you start a process with `<proc> &` inside your script. There is a risk that the processes are not terminated and will hang. Then you have to find them and kill the pids. You can track your started processes  like this: `my_child_PID=$!` to prevent hanging processes.

Comment: The main purpose of a `bash` script is to run *other* programs (which themselves could have memory leaks, but that's a different issue). The only memory a `bash` script uses is for its parameters, but if your script is managing so much data that its memory usage is an issue, you are using the wrong language.

Comment: @chepner Actually I am not  sure if my script is causing memory leak or not  . It is a pure bash script only ,not calling any other language binaries . So I just wanted to know how we can analyze the memory allocation for a bash script ,So that I can be sure that my script is not causing any problem in the environment .

Comment: Don't waste your time looking for memory leaks until you actually have a problem.  Memory leaks alone are not a problem; only programs that are allocating a lot of memory in the first place that subsequently do not release that memory are. And again, any script that might be using that much memory in the first place should not be written in `bash`, whether or not a leak is possible.

Comment: Ah okk . So what I understood  is that in normal  bash scripts memory allocation and de-allocation will be taken care by the system itself and programmer don't have to worry about it . Is that correct @chepner

Answer (score 2):

My definition of memory leak (from wikipedia) : In computer science, a memory leak is a type of resource leak that occurs when a computer program incorrectly manages memory allocations[1] in such a way that memory which is no longer needed is not released.

So the fork bomb doesn't qualify as the memory is still needed.

You can't manage memory yourself with bash, so no, you can't create memory leaks within a bug free version of pure bash code.

So if that is not the case (you have bug or use external code), the answer is yes and you can use a tool like Valgrind. Either using it on your bash script or on the calls of external code (from within the bash script).

It supports many platform and works with any language.

Comment: So how can we track the different memory spaces (like stack,heap,text etc)  for a bash script ? Or are all these concepts applicable for a bash script

Comment: `, you can't have memory leaks.` - Not correct, a simple case is where you add a c binary - which you compiled yourself- as a bash builtin and what if the binary had leaks..

Comment: Yes .Exactly @sjsam . So how do we track such issues for a bash script ?

Comment: So your way to create a memory leak in the language bash is to use another language. Ok... Use valgrind. I mean, you're asking if a sphere can cut you, I answer no and you answer, what if I stick a knife?

Comment: @LittleNooby No . Another language mentioned above is one scenario . :) valgrind i have seen with C++ . If  you are not using another language , and only pure bash script then is  it like there wont be any memory leaks ?

Comment: So without using any external tools like valgrind we can't see the memory allocation    ( stack space,heap space ) for a particular script  ? No inbuilt command will show like that info , like size command for C ?

Comment: No but you can use Valgrind (or alike) on each call of an external script without disturbing the functionalities of your script ( it will be slower and consume more memory of course but the result would be the same).

Comment: @LittleNooby `sjsam's` point is that `bash` is written in `c`, so you can, of course, have [memory leaks in bash](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gnu.bash.bug/-6KzAOGXgfs). It would be more precise to say that can't `create` memory leaks in a perfectly bug-free version of bash using pure bash code.

Comment: Well, if you must consider bugs and other languages, the answer would always be yes, whatever the language may be. Or am I wrong and there are somewhere some languages that can handle their own bugs (or never manage memory from code to CPU instructions) and external code errors ? That is what I don't understand and we seem to disagree about.

Comment: @LittleNooby I don't see why you couldn't have proprietary languages where the answer is no. But re-thinking this, I think the answer in `bash` is `yes` regardless of whether the version you're using is bug free, i.e. I think the classic fork bomb fits most definitions of a memory leak

Comment: Ah, maybe there is my misunderstanding. I don't consider a fork bomb as a memory leak. I thought a memory leak is memory allocated to a program which it doesn't free before ending and thus you cannot get back that memory without restarting the system. And for a fork bomb, the programs using the memory are not ended, and you can get back the memory given you've enough memory left to launch the kill instruction.